# Java-8 filtering two sets with lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I Have two sets of Roles. One from a database, another from UI. I also wrote comparing method of two Roles based on the giving name of the Role.

Problem: I'd like to extract role (keep one from database) if the compare value returns true using lambdas expression.

The `matchingRoleNames` work well, but I'm looking the best lambdas practices to do that without for loop.
This is my set result which worked fine:

```
Set<Role> rolesFromUI = user.getRolesFromUI();
Stream <Role> roleStreamFromDB = roleService.getAllRolesStreamFromDatabase();

Set<Role> matchingRoleNames = roleStreamFromDB.filter(role-> 
        {   
            for(Role roleTmp:rolesFromUI){
                if(roleTmp.compareTo(role)==0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        })

public int compareTo(Role role){
      return this.roleName.compareTo(role.getRoleName());       
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

instead of using the for each loop inside the `filter` intermediate operation of the first stream, you can just stream over the other set and see if any of the elements in that match any element of the first stream.

i.e:

```
Set<Role> matchingRoleNames = roleStreamFromDB.filter(e -> rolesFromUI.stream().anyMatch( x -> x.compareTo(e) == 0))
                                              .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Can we also add Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new) to filter DB roles ? What is the benefict ?

Answer (score 1):

As you are saying that you want to compare roles by name, you can do what you want by first collecting the names of the UI roles to a `Set` and then, when filtering the DB roles, just check if the name of the current role is in the set:

```
// Collect UI role names
Set<String> uiRoleNames = user.getRolesFromUI().stream()
    .map(Role::getRoleName)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());

// Filter DB roles
Set<Role> filteredRoles = roleService.getAllRolesStreamFromDatabase()
    .filter(role -> uiRoleNames.contains(role.getRoleName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This is both simple and efficient, because the `Set` returned by `Collectors.toSet()` is expected to be efficient for lookups (this means that its `contains` method will be `O(1)` for the average case).

If you want to be 100% sure that the returned set will be `O(1)` for `contains`, you might collect the UI role names as follows:

```
Set<String> uiRoleNames = user.getRolesFromUI().stream()
    .map(Role::getRoleName)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Comment: Hi Mr Schaffner, what do you mean by O(1) ?

Comment: @BertGuim Hi, sorry I didn't explain. `O(1)` means that the method runs in constant time, i.e. it takes the same time to execute, no matter if the set contains 10 elements or 20 million elements.

Comment: Got it, very interesting.

Comment: Can we also add Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new) to filter DB roles ? If yes, does that gives the same benefict for o(1) ?

Comment: @BertGuim Actually, `Collectors.toSet()` internally creates a `HashSet` (which has constant lookup time), though this is not guaranteed by the spec. So, if you want to be 100% sure that the returned `Set` interface is in fact an instance of the `HashSet` class, then you should use `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`, which explicitly creates a `HashSet`. Remember: the whole idea behind this approach is to have the UI role names in a `HashSet`, so that using `contains` when filtering the DB roles is efficient.

Comment: @BertGuim As to collect the DB roles by using `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)` instead of just `Collectors.toSet()`, it depends on what you plan to do with that set. In general, using `Collectors.toSet()` is enough, but you can always be extra-careful.